# Python3 Pandas dataframes: beside columns names are there also columns labels?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, label

Many database management systems, such as Oracle, SQL Server or even statistical software like SAS, allow having, beside field names, also field labels. 
E.g., in DBMS one may have a table called "Table1" with, among other fields, two fields called "income_A" and "income_B". 
Now, in the DBMS logic, "income_A" and "income_B" are the field **names**. 
Beside a name, those two fields can *also* have plain English labels associated to them, which clarify the actual *meaning* of those two fields; such as "*A - Income of households with dependable children where both parents work and they have a post-degree level of education*" and "*B - Income of empty-nesters households where only one works*".

Is there anything like that in Python3 Pandas dataframes?

I mean, I know I can give a dataframe column a "label" (which is, seen from the above DBMS perspective, more like a "name", in the sense that you can use it to refer to the column itself).

But can I also associate a longer description to the column, something that I can choose to display instead of the column "label" in print-outs and reports or that I can save into dataframe exports, e.g., in MS Excel format? Or do I have to do it all using data dictionaries, instead?

Comment: There isn't any alias support in pandas.  It's pretty easy though to build a dictionary of alias names such as  `alias = {'field_name': 'Field Name', etc...}` and then when you want to display a dataframe just use `df.rename(columns=alias).to_excel()` or `df.rename(columns=alias).head() `

Comment: @MichaelGardner, thank you for your reply. That's what I suspected and that is indeed what I am currently doing. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem that there is a way to store such meta info other than in the columns name. But the column name can be quite verbose. I tested up to 100 characters. Make sure to pass it as a collection.

Such a long name could be annoying to use for indexing in the code. You could use loc/iloc or assign the name to a string for use in indexing.

```
In[10]: pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4],columns=['how long can this be i want to know please tell me'])

Out[10]: 
   how long can this be i want to know please tell me
0                                                  1 
1                                                  2 
2                                                  3 
3                                                  4
```

This page shows that the columns don't really have any attributes to play with other than the lablels. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html

There is some more info you can get about a dataframe: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html